# Will the job schedule obey Daylight Saving rules?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, jobs

We have an Oracle 11g Scheduler Job that was created with a start date of `08/AUG/15 05:00:00.100000000 PM AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY` and a Repeat_INTERVAL of `FREQ=DAILY`. Sydney, as a city, observes Daylight Saving. I'm wondering if this job schedule will honour the change in Daylight Saving, or is the `AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY` component meaningless?

Answer (score 2):

> If you want the job to follow DST rules then you need to use a named timezone that follows the DST rules you want to use.

Yes, as you have provided the named time zone in your start date value.

**Reference:**[DBMS_SCHEDULER or DBMS_JOB And DST / Timezones Explained (Doc ID 467722.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=436057453486444&id=467722.1&_adf.ctrl-state=ovauu5hc5_366)